# how to access dictionary keys as index for list indexing in django template

Tags: django, django-templates

i have a list selCategories and a dictionary categories.

```
{{ selCategories }} // prints [1,1,0,0,1]
{% for id,category in categories.items %}
  {{ selCategories.0 }}     //prints 1                  
   {{ selCategories.id }}    //not printing anything
   {{ id }}                 //prints id values such as 1,2,3,4,5
<input type="checkbox"  {% if selCategories.id == 1 %} checked {% endif %}>// empty checkbox
{% endfor %}
```

here selCategories=[1,1,0,0,1]
categories={1:"Real",2:"education",3:"health",4:"food",5:"tourism"}
how can i get the value of {{ selCategories.id }} so that i can use it in other html attributes

Comment: Are you sure this is Jinja and not Django template language?

Comment: i am using this in django template